# Restore messages from old whatsapp file

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore, samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-galaxy-s-6

i need to restore old messages from a year and a half ago that i have the files of but everytime i load it onto the phone it does not load those messages, can anyone help me? it is also no longer the same phone...
S5 to S6

Comment: Isn't there an online backup of whatsapp files? Like in Google drive? If not, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A year and half? I don't think you can do that because WhatsApp changed the encryption system of messages a couple of months ago.

Below is my WhatsApp message backup.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to put it. But I realized something. My friend and I used to exchange phones. At one time after i use his phone and remove his WhatsApp account to  mine, though different numbers, WhatsApp gives me the option to restore backup from drive or SD. When I skip the drive and choose SD, it restores my friend's messages and media to my account and they are visible.. 
So I think if you have the backup file you can put it in the right WhatsApp directory and get everything going